# TinyMCE protect part of text from delete and modification

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to protect certain parts of a TinyMCE text while letting other parts be editable.
Text protected by Noneditable can't be partially selected and that part can still be erased.
So it is not suitable for things like update signatures.
Is there some other way/plugin that prevents delete and maybe still supports partial selected.